# ARC and Message Forwarding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, message-forwarding

I tried to implement Message Forwarding.
Xcode 5, ARC is ON, new default iPhone project.
[I read a documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html)

I have two custom classes in my project: `Hello` and `World`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Hello : NSObject
    - (void) say;
@end

#import "Hello.h"
#import "World.h"

@implementation Hello

- (void) say {
    NSLog(@"hello!");
}

-(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
    NSLog(@"forward invocation");
    World *w = [[World alloc] init];
    if ([w respondsToSelector:[invocation selector]]) {
        [invocation invokeWithTarget:w];
    } else {
        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector: [invocation selector]];
    }
}

-(NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
    NSLog(@"method signature");    
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (! signature) {
        World *w = [[World alloc] init];
        signature = [w methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    }
    return signature;
}

@end
```

World is simple:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface World : NSObject
    - (void) spin;
@end

#import "World.h"
@implementation World

- (void) spin {
    NSLog(@"spin around");
}

@end
```

In my AppDelegate i wrote three simple lines:

```
Hello  *me = [[Hello alloc] init];
[me say];
[me spin];
```

And compiler give me an error: `AppDelegate.m:23:9: No visible @interface for 'Hello' declares the selector 'spin'` and doesn't build a project. When I retype it: `[me performSelector:@selector(spin)];` - it works fine.

Code `[me spin]` works when ARC is OFF only (but compiler generates a warning `AppDelegate.m:23:9: 'Hello' may not respond to 'spin'`).

My questions: why? and How can I use ARC with message forwarding?

Comment: May be... but there is no answer there, I think.

Comment: So I can't use sending messages like `[me spin];` anymore?

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to explain in my answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring me as id:

```
 id me = [[Hello alloc] init];
 [me say];
 [me spin];
```

Comment: That would work if you include "World.h" in that source file, so that the compiler *knows* that there is a `spin` method.

Comment: Doesn't work `AppDelegate.m:23:5: Multiple methods named 'spin' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes`

Comment: Yes, this can only work if there is only one method named `spin` (or maybe more, but with the same signature).